# Downgrading CiviCRM to use an older extension

Tags: extension, upgrade

I am trying to use the [civicrm document storage](https://civicrm.org/extensions/documents) extension. It turns out that CiviCRM 4.4 and 4.3 supported this extension. My question is, is there a way to downgrade CiviCRM 4.6.3 to either 4.4 or 4.3 or is there a way that 4.6.3 supports document storage.

PS:I have 4.6.3 installed and is running it on Drupal 7. I have done quite a lot on the site thus can not simply install a new instance of CiviCRM.

Comment: Is it this extension you are thinking of? https://civicrm.org/extensions/documents It is made by @Jaap Jansma , maybe ask him...?

Comment: Yeah thats the extension I had seen. I am kinda new, how do I ask him?

Comment: I think he should have been automatically notified by setting @ infront of his username. Or you can contact him directly on his email (which is his name, with a dot between first name and last name, and @civicoop.org)

Answer (score 4):

I think (with @Xavier) a safer path then downgrading would be to upgrade the extension. You need this extension: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.documents and you should certainly speak to @JaapJansma about upgrading it. But I would bet it is an easier job than downgrading CiviCRM?

Answer (score 3):

In the case of many extensions, they may not be marked as "officially" supporting a certain version but still work file. I suggest you manually copy the extension to your server (auto-download won't work with "unsupported" releases) and enable it. Backup your database first!!

If you encounter any errors with this process, this is great feedback to give the extension maintainer. File an issue on the GitHub project page of the extension giving as many details as possible. It will help him to know that

a. Someone is interested in using the extenison with the latest version of Civi.

b. There are specific things to fix.

Comment: Thanx, I will sure try that. Again thanx for the input.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think civi ever had a document storage in a previous version and then got removed. What you saw might have been an extension.

As for downgrading: you would need to find all the changes in the structure of the databases and in the content, and reverse them.

I had to do it once and it was only a few minor versions. It's not trivial, time consuming and error prone. I would avoid it as much as possible, and if the document storage you have seen need to be upgraded to work with the latest civicrm version, I'd much rather invest my time there rather than trying to downgrade